# Partitioning on multiple columns?

Tags: count, partitioning

I'm working a personal project and I have this table called Movies, Formatted as such:

| Movie_Title | Genre | Release_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Wick 4 | Action-Thriller-Crime | 2023 |

And I split it up by genre into a table as below because
I want to count the number of genres create per Release Year:

| Movie_Title | Genre | Release_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Avatar | Action | 2022 |
| Avatar | Adventure | 2022 |
| Avatar | Sci-Fi | 2022 |
| Ant-Man | Action | 2022 |
| Ant-Man | Adventure | 2022 |
| Ant-Man | Sci-Fi | 2022 |
| John Wick 4 | Action | 2023 |
| John Wick 4 | Thriller | 2023 |
| John Wick 4 | Crime | 2023 |

To do that I tried to partition it by two columns 'Genre' and 'Release_Year' using this Query:

Select Genre, Count(Genre) OVER (Partition by Genre,Release_Year) as Num_genre, Release_Year
FROM Movies

My Expected outcome is a table as such:

| Genre | Num_genre | Release_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Action | 2 | 2022 |
| Sci-Fi | 2 | 2022 |
| Adventure | 2 | 2022 |
| Action | 1 | 2023 |
| Thriller | 1 | 2023 |
| Crime | 1 | 2023 |

However when I run that query I end up getting a lot of dupes (same genre same year same count) back and it ends up looking like this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1DAp.png)

Any help would be really appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` aggregation clause:

```sql
SELECT
  Genre,
  COUNT(1) AS Num_genre,
  Release_Year
FROM
  Movies
GROUP BY
  Genre,
  Release_Year
;
```